# Remove button overlays from SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I have a very simple SupportMapFragment to display a small Google map which I use in this view
[image]

The idea is that the user can click it to view a full screen map.
How can I get rid of the +/- button from the map?
If it's not possible, is there an alternative method to get a map?

Here is my MapFragment code:

```
public class CustomMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    private static LatLng mPosFija;

    public CustomMapFragment() {
        super();

    }

    public static CustomMapFragment newInstance(LatLng position) {
        CustomMapFragment fragment = new CustomMapFragment();
        mPosFija = position;
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (getMap() != null) {
            initMap();
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Map ready for use!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initMap();
    }

    private void initMap() {
        Log.v("CustomMapFragment", "initMap");
        if (getMap() != null) {
            UiSettings settings = getMap().getUiSettings();
            settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
            settings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

            getMap().clear();
            getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mPosFija, 5));
            getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mPosFija).draggable(false));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for my DialogFragment that adds the mapFragment to the view:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity()) == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID
                || GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity()) == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING) {
            Log.e("HERE", "Google play not active");

            TextViewFragment tvf = new TextViewFragment();
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapview, tvf).commit();

        } else {

            CustomMapFragment mMapFragment = CustomMapFragment.newInstance(new LatLng(offer.latitude, offer.longitude));
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapview, mMapFragment).commit();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so this was staring me in the face and was as simple as

```
UiSettings settings = getMap().getUiSettings();
            settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
            settings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            settings.setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```